# Pandas Dataframe Functionality

Tags: dataframe

I would like to create dataframes using excel spreadsheets as source data.  I need to transform the data series from the format used to store the data in the excel spreadsheets to the dataframe variable end product.

I would like to know if users have experience in using various python methods to accomplish the following:

-data series transform: I have a series that includes one data value per month, but would like to expand the table of values to include one value per day using an index (or perhaps column with date values). So if table1 has a month based index and table2 has a daily index how can I convert table1 values to the table2 based index.

-dataframe sculpting: the data I am working with is not similar in length, some data sets are longer than others.  By what methods is it possible to find the shortest series length in a column in the context of a multicolumn dataframe?

Essentially, I would like to take individual tables from workbooks and combine them into a single dataframe that uses a single index value as the basis for their presentation.  My workbook tables may have data point frequencies of daily, weekly, or monthly and I would like to build a dataframe that uses the daily index as a basis for the table elements while including an element for each day in series that are weekly and monthly.

I am looking at the Pandas library, but perhaps there are other libraries that I have overlooked with additional functionality.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, try something like:

```
df1 = df1.resample('1d').first()
df2.merge(df1)
```

That will upsample your monthly or weekly dataframes and merge it with your daily dataframe. Take a look at the [interpolate method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) to fill in missing values. To get the name of the shortest column try this out:

```
df.count().idxmin()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this helped, while searching the documentation I also discovered df.fillna().  Both will be helpful in the project I am working on!  Thanks!